# Colorizing image ignores alpha channel — why and how to fix?

Tags: ios, opacity, quartz-2d, alphablending, colorize

Here's what I'm trying to do: **On the left** is a generic, uncolorized RGBA image that I've created off-screen and cached for speed (it's very slow to create initially, but very fast to colorize with any color later, as needed). It's a square image with a circular swirl. Inside the circle, the image has an alpha/opacity of 1. Outside the circle, it has an alpha/opacity of 0. I've displayed it here inside a UIView with a background color of `[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]`. **On the right** is what happens when I attempt to colorize the image by filling a solid red rectangle over the top of it after setting `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor)`.

[image: Uncolorized]
[image: Colorized Incorrectly]

That's not what I want, nor what I expected. Evidently, colorizing a completely transparent pixel (e.g., alpha value of 0) results in the full-on fill color for some strange reason, rather than remaining transparent as I would have expected.

What I want is actually this:

[image: Colorized Correctly]

Now, *in this particular case*, I can set the clipping region to a circle, so that the area outside the circle remains untouched — and that's what I've done here as a workaround.

But in my app, I also need to be able to colorize arbitrary shapes where I don't know the clipping/outline path. One example is colorizing white text by overlaying a gradient. How is this done? I suspect there must be some way to do it efficiently — and generally, with no weird path/clipping tricks — using image masks... but I have yet to find a tutorial on this. Obviously it's possible because I've seen colored-gradient text in other games.

Incidentally, what I can't do is start with a gradient and clip/clear away parts I don't need — because (as shown in the example above) my uncolorized source images are, in general, grayscale rather than pure white. So I really need to start with the uncolorized image and then colorize it.

p.s. — `kCGBlendModeMultiply` also has the same flaws / shortcomings / idiosyncrasies when it comes to colorizing partially transparent images. Does anyone know *why* Apple decided to do it that way? It's as if the Quartz colorizing code treats RGBA(0,0,0,0) as RGBA(0,0,0,1), i.e., it completely ignores and destroys the alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that you can take that will work is to construct a mask from the original image and then invoke the CGContextClipToMask() method before rendering your image with the multiply blend mode set. Here is the CoreGraphics code that would set the mask before drawing the image to color.

```
  CGContextRef context = [frameBuffer createBitmapContext];
  CGRect bounds = CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, width, height );
  CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, maskImage.CGImage);
  CGContextDrawImage(context, bounds, greyImage.CGImage);
```

The slightly more tricky part will be to take the original image and generate a maskImage. What you can do for that is write a loop that will examine each pixel and write either a black or white pixel as the mask value. If the original pixel in the image to color is completely transparent, then write a black pixel, otherwise write a white pixel. Note that the mask value will be a 24BPP image. Here is some code to give you the right idea.

```
  uint32_t *inPixels = (uint32_t*) MEMORY_ADDR_OF_ORIGINAL_IMAGE;
  uint32_t *maskPixels = malloc(numPixels * sizeof(uint32_t));
  uint32_t *maskPixelsPtr = maskPixels;

  for (int rowi = 0; rowi < height; rowi++) {
    for (int coli = 0; coli < width; coli++) {
      uint32_t inPixel = *inPixels++;
      uint32_t inAlpha = (inPixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
      uint32_t cval = 0;
      if (inAlpha != 0) {
        cval = 0xFF;
      }
      uint32_t outPixel = (0xFF << 24) | (cval << 16) | (cval << 8) | cval;
      *maskPixelsPtr++ = outPixel;
    }
  }
```

You will of course need to fill in all the details and create the graphics contexts and so on. But the general idea is to simply create your own mask to filter out drawing of the red parts around the outside of the circle.